# What is the meaning of ModuleDepth in the doc/docstrip system?

Tags: doc

What is the meaning of the counter `Module Depth` in the `doc/docstrip` system? I read the package documentation but I am still not clear if I understand it correctly. Can someone give a concrete example of Depth 3 ? My use case, I am parsing each line of the `macrocode` environment. If it starts with a `%` I color it, if it is a guard I make it another color, and not rely on the doc's `Module`, just want to understand the background a bit more.  `Module` is clear is just a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

`doc`(`strip`) allows different blocks of code to be marked

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
some code
%<*foo>
code at depth 1
more code at depth 1
%<*bar>
depth 2
%</bar>
%</foo>
more code
%    \end{macrocode}
```

The parts inside the marked regions can be included or excluded from extracted files depending on options given.

In simple packages, the main code is likely at the outer level and the code in the marked regions is some kind of conditional/optional code.

In generated documentation the `doc` package uses normal upright `\ttfamily`  for the main code and an "alt" typeface defaulting to italic typewriter for the nested blocks.

More complicated source files that are generating multiple files may have all the code in at least one level of docstrip guard, so they would come out all in itaic monospace which s not very readable.

A setting , such as

```
\setcounter{StandardModuleDepth}{2}
```

says to typeset code blocks up to depth 2 in the default upright font and only highlight regions that are nested more deeply than that.

Comment: So simplistically if I have <foo>,<bar><package> I have ModuleDepth 3? or does nesting makes a difference?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides yes more or less, If you have boolean combinations of doctrip guards it does whatever it does, (I'd have to check the code) it doesn't really matter it's just a course flag switching to a different font at some point. It has no effect on the generated code, just intended to mark heavily docstrip-guarded sections in italic.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Comment: Tested a minimal based on your explanation, gracefully with doc3 you get a slanted font!.